# Corrupted Date Taken

Tags: metadata, jpeg, date

Some of my older images are showing Date Taken later than the actual date that the camera took the image.
The EXIF data shows the correct Date Taken in the field APP12::PictureInfo\TimeDate\DateTimeOriginal\0

I've tried copying DateTimeOriginal to Files' Date Created using Exiftool, `exiftool "-FileCreateDate<DateTimeOriginal" -r \1999\*.jpg` but Windows and other programs still show the wrong date data.
Is FileCreateDate the field that is used by Windows to display Date Taken? I can't see an Exif field with that name.
Thanks in advance,
Steve

Answer (score 2):

That `DateTimeOriginal` tag is located in an extremely old and outdated group, not in the EXIF data.  Windows wouldn't know how to read the APP14 PictureInfo group and I doubt that there are many programs outside of exiftool and maybe exiv2 that would even be able to see that data.

The command you would want to use with exiftool to copy that data to the EXIF timestamps would be
`exiftool "-AllDates<PictureInfo:DateTimeOriginal" /path/to/files/`

Comment: Thank you. Yes the Pictures are over 20 years old. Won't that command also overwrite Modified Date?

Comment: It will overwrite the embedded `EXIF:ModifyDate`, but not the file system `FileModifyDate`.  The `EXIF:ModifyDate` isn't really used in anything anyway.  But if you want to avoid writing it, I'd suggest at least writing the `CreateDate` tag as well.  So you could use `"-DateTimeOriginal<PictureInfo:DateTimeOriginal" "-CreateDate<PictureInfo:DateTimeOriginal"`.

Comment: For anyone else interested, the exiftool forum thread is [here](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=12664.0).